# How do I serialize and deserialize in Java when I have a black box to convert to/from a byte array?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class that is something like the following:

```
public class Foo {
  static byte[] convertToArray(Foo f);
  static Foo convertToFoo(byte[] ba);
}
```

How can I use convertToArray and convertToFoo to allow Foo to implement java.io.Serializable? The default serialization procedure doesn't seem like a good solution for my class because it would require changing a lot of other classes to implement Serializable. However, I already have a way to go to and from bytes, so there should be an easy way for Foo to implement serializable without having to declare all dependent members as Serializable. I suspect overriding readObject and writeObject is the way to go, but what is the correct way to do this, since these are instance methods with return type void?

Comment: If most of your classes have a means of being serialised why doesn't your Foo class do the same thing?

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I'm really having problems to understand this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Externalizable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html), which is a subinterface of Serializable. Its `readExternal` and `writeExternal` methods delegate the serialization details to the programmer, which sounds appropriate in your case.

During deserialization (in your implementation of `readExternal`), you will need to use `Foo.convertToFoo` to convert the bytes from an `ObjectInput` to a `Foo` object, and then copy all of the state of that `Foo` object into `this`.

A snippet from the Javadoc that describes the semantics of Externalizable:

> Only the identity of the class of an
>   Externalizable instance is written in
>   the serialization stream and it is the
>   responsibility of the class to save
>   and restore the contents of its
>   instances. The writeExternal and
>   readExternal methods of the
>   Externalizable interface are
>   implemented by a class to give the
>   class complete control over the format
>   and contents of the stream for an
>   object and its supertypes. These
>   methods must explicitly coordinate
>   with the supertype to save its state.
>   These methods supersede customized
>   implementations of writeObject and
>   readObject methods.

Comment: Using this method, you would only have to create a new instance of `Foo` then call `foo.readExternal(input);` to restore the object instance's state. You'll have to implement your own serialized data structure though...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class is `final` then you probably want to use a serial proxy (see Effective Java). Implement `Serializable`, but make `readObject`, `readObjectNoData` and `writeObject` throw an exception. Use `writeReplace` to produce a serialisable proxy object containing the binary data. In the proxy, use `readResolve` to create a `Foo` from the data.

```
public final class Foo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
    private static final ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields = { }
    static byte[] convertToArray(Foo f) { ... }
    static Foo convertToFoo(byte[] ba) { ... }

    private void writeObject(
        ObjectOutputStream out {
    ) throws IOException {
        throw new NotSerializableException();
    }
    private void readObject(
        ObjectInputStream in
    ) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        throw new NotSerializableException();
    }
    private void readObjectNoData( 
    ) throws ObjectStreamException {
        throw new NotSerializableException();
    }
    private Object writeReplace() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return new FooSerialProxy(this);
    }
}

/* pp */ final class FooSerialProxy implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
    private final byte[] data;
    /* pp */ FooSerialProxy(Foo foo) {
        this.data = Foo.convertToArray(foo);
    }
    private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return Foo.convertToFoo(data);
    }
}
```